# Error Updating SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get an error when l try to update my table. The table consist of 6 columns which l display in a data grid view on the windows form. The ID column is displayed in a label on the form to prevent users from editing.

Now when l try to update I get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "lblId.Text" could not be bound.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Here is my update code:

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand ("UPDATE jimmy SET Id=@Id, 
         FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName, Telephone=@Telephone, 
        Address=@Address, City=@City,Country=@Country WHERE @Id=lblId.Text", cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", lblID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtfirstname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtlastname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", txttelephone.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtaddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtcity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", txtcountry.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Updated");
    cleartext();
}
```

Comment: Thats not a SQL issue, that is an issue of you pulling the value from your Label.  Try debugging and getting the value from the Label and see what happens.  Maybe put it into a variable.  If it is disabled that may be the issue, you cant grab values from disabled objects I beleive.

Comment: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 4):

The error came from your SQL command text at the `WHERE` clause.

It should be

```
WHERE Id = @Id
```

Instead of

```
WHERE @Id = lblId.Text
```

You can't say to SQL Server to read a text from your textbox controller by putting `lblId.Text` directly into the SQL Command text.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE @Id=lblId.Text` should be `WHERE Id=@Id` since `lblId.Text` is most probably your UI control value you want to pass as parameter value which anyways you are doing saying `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", lblID.Text);`